# Outlook middle aligning text it should not be

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, campaign-monitor

I have the following code (is for campaign monitor):

Left Image:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top">
    <tr>
        <td class="content" valign="top" height="200"
            style="padding: 0 20px 20px 20px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
            width="600">
            <img src="./images/logo.gif" alt=""
                 width="260" align="left"
                 editable="true" hspace="10"
                 label="Image"/>
            <multiline label="Description">Enter your
                description here.
            </multiline>
            <span class="button">
                <singleline label="Link">Link</singleline>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Right Image:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top">
    <tr>
        <td class="content" valign="top" height="200"
            style="padding: 0 20px 20px 20px; color: #333; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
            width="600">
            <img src="./images/logo.gif" alt=""
                 width="260" align="right"
                 editable="true" hspace="10"
                 label="Image"/>
            <multiline label="Description">Enter your
                description here.
            </multiline>
            <span class="button">
                <singleline label="Link">Link</singleline>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On Outlook The text next to the image is middle aligning with the image when it should be top aligning.

All other clients appear to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding vertical-align: top; to the style attribute within the td instead of using the attribute valign?

Also maybe move the height to the style attribute to.